# Encoding MySQL, PHP and CSV file

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

I have a mysql database with some chinese keywords that i need to compare against some keywords in a CSV file using PHP.

I seem to have a problem with the encoding, when i compare 2 keywords i know are the same (with chinese characters) the script says they are different.

I use "SET NAMES utf8" at the beginning of the script for the database.
the collation for the keywords field on the table is utf8_bin.

on the script i also used

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
header('Content-Type: text/xml, charset=UTF-8; encoding=UTF-8');
```

i read the CSV file with

```
    $data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE
```

and my comparison line is like this

```
    $database_keyword == CSV_keyword
```

regarding the CSV file i have used notepad++ to try to change the encoding, but still not working.

thanks a lot.

edit: I am on Windows 7

EDIT: ADDING SOLUTION
it might help someone out there, i found that my issue was caused by the BOM being included on the strings from the csv files.
I managed to remove it by using this function

```
    private function rmBOM($string) { 
        if(substr($string, 0,3) == pack('CCC',0xef,0xbb,0xbf)) { 
            $string=substr($string, 3); 
        } 
        return $string; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have limited experience on Windows since I work usually on Linux, but I have worked in integration projects dealing with different charsets (encodings).

1. Be sure the database connection is in UTF mode. Have a look at this [document](http://www.synet.sk/php/en/230-php-drivers-for-microsoft-sql-server-mssql-sqlsrv-utf8).
2. Be sure the csv file is in UTF. You can force conversion with the iconv() function.